# Secure boot with unified kernel image on openSuSE?

Tags: uefi, opensuse, secure-boot, initrd, dracut

I am trying to install OpenSuSE Tumbleweed on a system with encrypted root partition. At first i tried to set up [GRUB](https://www.8bytes.org/posts/opensuse-full-disk-encryption/), but it refused to recognize a LUKS-encrypted partition.

Currently I am trying to use a [unified kernel image](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_kernel_image) which signes both the kernel and the initrd with a Secure Boot key to prevent tampering. Debian has [sicherboot](https://github.com/julian-klode/sicherboot) for that purpose, Arch has [sbupdate](https://github.com/andreyv/sbupdate).

Dracut, the initrd used in SUSE, also seems to have [this functionality built-in](https://nwildner.com/posts/2021-04-10-secureboot-fedora/). Unfortunately, the dracut postinstall script (present in `/usr/lib/module-init-tools/regenerate-initrd-posttrans` and reproduced below) seems to hardcode the dracut commandline. Is there any other way to automate generation of unified kernel images after RPM updates?

```bash
#!/bin/sh
#
# Packages that install kernels or kernel-modules create a flag
#
#   /run/regenerate-initrd/<kernel image>
# 
# to have the initrd for <kernel image> generated, or
#
#   /run/regenerate-initrd/all
#
# to have all initrds generated. This script is called from posttrans
# and takes care of generating the initrds

: ${DRACUT:=/usr/bin/dracut}
if [ ! -x "$DRACUT" ]; then
    echo "${0##*/}: dracut is not installed, not rebuilding the initrd" >&2
    exit 0
fi

dir=/run/regenerate-initrd

if ! test -d "$dir"; then
    exit 0
fi
for f in "$dir"/*; do
    case $f in
        "$dir/*")
        [ -e "$f" ] || break;;
    esac
    # check if we are in a build chroot
    if ! [  -f /etc/fstab -a ! -e /.buildenv -a -x "$DRACUT" ] ; then
        echo "Please run \"$DRACUT -f --regenerate-all\" as soon as your system is complete." >&2
        rm "$dir"/*
        exit 0
    fi
    break
done

if test -e "$dir/all"; then
    rm "$dir"/*
    "$DRACUT" -f --regenerate-all
    exit
fi
err=0
for f in "$dir"/*; do
    case $f in
        "$dir/*")
        [ -e "$f" ] || break;;
    esac
    rm "$f"
    image=${f##*/}
    kver=${image#*-}
    if ! test -e "/boot/$image"; then
        echo "$0: /boot/$image does not exist, initrd won't be generated"
        continue
    fi
    if ! "$DRACUT" -f "/boot/initrd-$kver" "$kver"; then
        err=$?
    fi
done
exit $err
```

Answer (score 1):

It seams [adding `uefi="yes"` to dracut.conf](https://gist.github.com/Neurognostic/259f1ba1e568b31f0732a4a18f399f9e) causes Dracut to produce unified images on the EFI partition (in the location [expected by systemd-boot](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/systemd-boot.7.html)), which should solve the issue [I haven't had the time to check this yet]

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this and can confirm that this works. I have an empty `/efi` directory so that systemd-gpt-auto-generator automounts the ESP in that directory when dracut tries to access it. So when dracut is invoked by `kernel-default` package `postinst` the UKI will automatically be placed in `/efi/EFI/Linux/` as required. Or if you need to regenerate it manually, then it's just `dracut -f --regenerate-all`